# Any idea to change the blank appearance on password

Tags: password, customization, appearance

whenever i edit the terminal or change password in linux it appears as blank(i.e it wont show the password), any idea to make appearance of it (as *)

i face the following difficulty

- i dont know how many characters i am typing for correct password

Any third party tool or tweak to make apperance of typing password as *?

Comment: @mikewhatever Consider that he knows what to do in this situation. But needs How to **show** the password as `***` stars.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a third-party tweak to show *'s or dots but I don't know any. It is supposed to appear blank for obvious security reasons. You will have to find out if the words you typed in was the correct password when you press ENTER. You could always count how many keys you typed in :)